# Accelerate and Optimze GA algorithm as feature selection for Regression Problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, genetic-algorithm, feature-selection

I am trying to compare ANOVA with the GA algorithm as feature selection then apply the selected set on various ML models and compare them in terms of MAE, RMSE and R2. I used the GA algorithm to do a feature selection for a regression problem. My dataset contains (78 features, 1 target, 1016 rows). I am facing with 3 problems:

1. The program is taking a long time to process one generation of GA.
2. Since I am new to GA, I am not sure whether the fitness function that I've used is good or not.
3. When comparing with ANOVA when used for ML models in terms of MAE, RMSE and R2, it gets worse results than GA results.

Any suggestions about the fitness function of my above-related issues?
Thanks in advance.

Below is a part of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import power_transform
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVR
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, ExtraTreesRegressor, AdaBoostRegressor, BaggingRegressor
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingRegressor
from deap import base, creator, tools, algorithms
import random
import warnings
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from multiprocessing import Pool


# Initialize TPU
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + 
os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# Load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv("CBECS_Office_Subset.csv")
original_feature_names = df.columns[:-1]  # Exclude the target variable

# Normalize the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

# Transform the data and ignore warnings during this process
with warnings.catch_warnings():
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
df = power_transform(df, method='yeo-johnson')
df = scaler.fit_transform(df)

X = df[:, :-1]
y = df[:, -1]

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# Models
models = {
   "Linear Regression": LinearRegression(),
   "Support Vector Machine": LinearSVR(),
   "Random Forest": RandomForestRegressor(),
   "Extra Trees Regressor": ExtraTreesRegressor(),
   "Adaboost Regressor": AdaBoostRegressor(),
   "MLP Regressor": MLPRegressor(),
   "Bagging Regressor": BaggingRegressor(),
   "Stacking Regressor": StackingRegressor(estimators=[
         ('lr', LinearRegression()),
         ('svm', LinearSVR()),
         ('rf', RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)),
         ('etr', ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)),
         ('ada', AdaBoostRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)),
         ('mlp', MLPRegressor()),
   ], final_estimator=LinearRegression())
   }

# Define the GA optimization function
# Create a fitness function that maximizes an aggregated error metric
creator.create("FitnessMin", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMin)

# Define genetic operators
toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.randint, 0, 1)  # Binary representation for feature selection
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, toolbox.attr_bool, n=len(X[0]))
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

# Define the evaluation function (fitness function)
def evaluate_individual(individual, model):
selected_features = [i for i, bit in enumerate(individual) if bit]

X_train_subset = X_train[:, selected_features]
X_test_subset = X_test[:, selected_features]

model.fit(X_train_subset, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_subset)

mae = np.mean(np.abs(y_test - y_pred))
rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean((y_test - y_pred) ** 2))
r2 = 1.0 - (np.sum((y_test - y_pred) ** 2) / np.sum((y_test - np.mean(y_test)) ** 2))

mape = np.mean(np.abs((y_test - y_pred) / y_test)) * 100

# Define an aggregation method, 
fitness = mae

return fitness,
```